# What could be the cause of eroded mortar in exterior brick?

Tags: walls, brick, mortar, weep-hole

This [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/365/should-i-fill-eroded-mortar-in-exterior-brick) actually reminded me of an issue with my exterior walls. I have the same problem with the vertical mortar being eroded/missing from several bricks at ground level on the exterior of my house. I live in Alabama, so we don't have much severe weather (unless you count ridiculous humidity), and I have no idea how this could have happened. The rest of the mortar is fine, but only a few joints are completely missing. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is this some purposefully built structural feature that I'm just oblivious toward - they seem to be fairly regularly spaced.

When the home inspector came by before we bought the house, he didn't mention anything about them, and I didn't really notice them until we moved in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gaps are there intentionally. They are **weep holes** which allow moisture to escape from inside your walls. [This website has some more information as well.](http://www.courierpress.com/news/inspectors-report-on-weep-holes-has-seller-in-a-quandary-ep-449189209-326480671.html)

Comment: Invalid URL now. could you paste the explanation in your answer instead?